Contradiction in nonstandard analysis?
I'm reading Infinitesimal Calculus by Henle and Kleinberg.
Note: $inf$ denotes the inifinitesimal, which is smaller than every real but larger than 0, by the book's definition.
In the book it shows that there are infinite integers by the following logic:
We can write the sentence in R hence also in HR (the extended hyperreal system):
$\forall x_1 \exists x_2 (x_1<x_2 \ \land I(x_2))$
$1/inf$, which is infinite, is in HR, hence we can find a integer number that is larger than it.
So far so good. But by the same logic we can also write a sentence that is true in HR:
$\forall x_1>0 \exists x_2>0 (x_1>x_2 \ \land R(x_2))$
let $x_1 = inf$, we can find an $x_2$ that is real but smaller than $inf$, which is in turn smaller than every positive real (by the definition of $inf$). So we get $x_2$ is also smaller than every positive real. But $x_2$ is itself real so there should be another positive real that is smaller than $x_2$. Hence the contradiction.
Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

How are you getting the second statement "by the same logic"? If inf is smaller than every real, you shouldn't be able to get $0<x_2<\operatorname{inf}$ with $x_2$ real.

What are $R(\cdot)$ and $I(\cdot)$? I also hope you mean that $inf$ is an infinitesimal, not the, as there are necessarily infinitely many of them.

My best guess is that $R(x_2)$ means $x_2$ is real, in which case your conclusion is false because you've applied Transfer incorrectly; you need to replace the reals with the hyperreals when you apply Transfer, so you can only conclude that there is a hyperreal $x_2$, not necessarily a real one.

Your predicate $I(x)$ seems to be "$x$ is a (hyper)integer", and you correctly deduced the existence of an infinite hyperinteger from the existence of an infinite hyperreal.
On the other hand, your predicate $R(x)$ seems to be "$x$ is a real number".  This is not an internal entity (in particular, the real numbers are not an internal set in the hyperreals), and therefore transfer does not apply here.  A correct version of your argument would simply show that for every infinitesimal, there is another even smaller one.
